Standard deviation of the mean for biased coin with all heads for first $N$ trials
Imagine that we have a biased coin but we only have $N$ trials to determine how much it is biased towards heads (we are resource limited in how many trials we can conduct). Say we assign a value of $0$ to tails and $1$ to heads, so if the coin was not biased the population mean would be $0.5$
If we flip the biased coin $N$ times and it comes up heads each and every time the sample mean would be one.
The sample standard deviation formula would give zero.
The standard deviation of the mean would $\mathrm{stdev}/\sqrt N$, also zero.
However, it does not seem like the uncertainty in our estimate of probability of heads should be zero, especially for a small number of trials.
If one of the trials gives a different answer then the standard deviation formulas seem to work out, but they break down in the case where discrete measurements just happen to give the same answer in all of the trials (all heads or all tails).
Is there an alternative way to estimate the variance in our measurement of the mean in these cases?
Also imagine that we're evaluating several biased coins and want to estimate which ones are more biased than others. We have $N$ trials for each coin. Some of them give a mix of heads/tails but some coins give just heads and others give just tails. Is there a consistent way to estimate the uncertainty in the sampled means for all these coins?

Are you sure you really need a variance estimate?  There exist good ways to test hypotheses, for instance, that do not require any variance estimate at all: search for "Clopper-Pearson" and "Rule of 3."  For obtaining a posterior distribution you will need a prior and a Bayesian approach, but that's dead simple using a Beta conjugate prior (those are good search terms).

Looks like Wilson Score Interval might be what I'm looking for.

I found the Wilson Score Interval to be useful in this case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval
